# How to fix "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH"?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use Selenium to change my IP using a code I found
but I am getting an error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "23.23.23.23:3128" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://%s' % PROXY)

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error by adding the executable path when creating the Chrome webdriver instance.

Here is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=ipaddress:port')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="your executable path",chrome_options=chrome_options)
 driver.get('https://www.myip.com/')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, I hope it helps :)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

prox = Proxy()
prox.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
prox.http_proxy = "ip_addr:port"
prox.socks_proxy = "ip_addr:port"
prox.ssl_proxy = "ip_addr:port"

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment but it keeps giving me the error ''chrome driver' executable needs to be in PATH'.

Comment: Try this  driver = webdriver.chrome(executable_path=r"path")